# c# Access denied to create a new file

Tags: c#, createfile

I want to create an xml file. I am the owner of the folder which will contain the created file. My code creates an empty file and when I debug I get an access denied error for this line

```
 Stream writeOutput = File.Create(Path.Combine(outputLocation, string.Format(FILEFORMAT, agent, Number, FILE_EXTENSIONS.XML)))
```

Help please

Here is my code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {

        using (Stream writeOutput = File.Create(Path.Combine(outputLocation, string.Format(FILEFORMAT, agent, Number, FILE_EXTENSIONS.XML))))
              {
                 using (Stream xmlOutput = OutputFileCreator.CreateOutputXMLFile(Number, rejectionReason))
                       {
                         byte[] buffer = new byte[xmlOutput.Length];
                         xmlOutput.Position = 0;
                         xmlOutput.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                         writeOutput.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                       }
              }    
    });
```

[image]

Comment: What is the path you're writing to? If you're running this on a windows machine, you might need to execute your program with administrator rights (default for any path from C:\ besides your user folders)

Comment: I edit my post with the folder and the empty created xml

Comment: Access denied... pretty clear message. The user under which the program is running has no write access to the folder. So check that user has write access to the path.

Comment: I m the owner of the folder, and I run Visual studio as admin

Comment: Are you sure that you're just getting this error because the file already exists? Maybe you need to pass some flag so that your program is allowed to overwrite.

Answer (score 2):

What is the Application Pool Identity that you are running this as?

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
```

Causes that code block run under the App Pool identity that has site collection administrator privileges.  Does that identity have the appropriate permissions?

See here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx

Comment: Yes , I am the administrator of the web application

Answer (score 1):

You may have to make your machine have access to the folder, not just your user. Try adding sharing permissions to everyone in the properties for the folder or YourMachineName$ to indicate your physical machine has access.

Comment: I am working on a remote machine, and I create this folder, if I don't have the right, could you please explain to me how it creates the file even if it's empty ?

Comment: You can actually create the file but not write into it?

Comment: I delete the folder and recreate it and overwrite in c# , and now it works ... thank you